# The content of ipa version is difference from direct debug from Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, distribution, ipa

I have a page which is for new install.

When user install this apps, the apps sure will go "survey" page.

This run correctly when i direct debug from Xcode within device.

However, I generate an ipa file and sync into device. The apps skipped "survey" page and direct go to another page.

Before sync, i had deleted the old apps.

Here is the checking logic. It just fyi.

```
DatabaseAction *getsurvey = [[[DatabaseAction alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray *survey = [getsurvey retrieveSurvey];
int check;
for(SurveyForm *form in survey){
    check = form.Submitted;
    break;
}

if(check == 1){
    Main_AllLatestNews *GtestClasssViewController=[[[Main_AllLatestNews alloc] initWithNibName:@"Main_AllLatestNews"  bundle:nil] autorelease];
    GtestClasssViewController.autodownload = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:GtestClasssViewController animated:NO];
}else{
    Menu_newUserForm *GtestClasssViewController=[[[Menu_newUserForm alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu_newUserForm"  bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:GtestClasssViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Did you try `NSLog` to check what happens inside the app? Are you building debug and distribution with the same preprocessor settings?

Comment: Your code checks only if the first survey has been submitted, is that what you want? Also the behaviour is undefined if the `survey` array is empty.

Comment: solved, i change the structure of sqlite.

Comment: Then, please answer your own question describing what the problem was.